# CLLocationManager not prompting the user and returns NULL

Tags: iphone, sdk, cllocationmanager

Till yetsterday everything was working fine on my iPhone. Starting today, I noticed that CLLocationManager does not prompt the user "this app wants to use your location" and proceeds to return me null in the didUpdateToLocation. I have tried signing my app with dev provisioning, adhoc and prod profiles. Also, I am making sure that I delete the app before trying this. Earlier the moment I would run the app first time, it would prompt me for push notifications and GPS prompt. But now, none of these prompts are showing up.

My App does a CLLocationmanager startupdatingLocation in AppDelegate --> applicationdidLaunch and applicationdidLaunchwithOptions. Also, CLLocationManager does not call my didFailWithError.

Comment: Is location services on in Settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replying to myself. I was using testflighapp.com for beta testing and I am not sure if that was causing it, but all I had to do was go ti iPhone-->Settings-->General-->Reset-->Reset Location Warnings.

Once I did that and ran my app, it did prompt me for GPS and everything started working fine after that.